# Can't locate shell script

Tags: search

I created a shell script that logs me in to a server. The script was in a directory that was added to `$PATH`

I think I might have deleted the script when not paying attention (not on purpose). I cannot find the script anymore. I tried several things:

1. use Spotlight (I'm using a Mac - spotlight does pretty much the same as `locate` afaik)
2. use `which [scriptname]`
3. go to root and type `find * | grep [scriptname]`

None of these solutions located the script. HOWEVER: the script is still working. Even after a reboot.

What is going on here? Is the script still somewhere on my drive?

Comment: It is surely on ur disk.

Comment: What does `type scriptname` say?

Comment: @pradeepchhetri As jwj013 is hinting, it may not be.  Not as a script, that is.

Comment: If the script is running after reboot, then what is starting it? Check the output of `crontab -l` of your user and root. How does it logon to the server? If `ssh` then you can find the process with `ps` and track down the parent process leading to the script and its details such as the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys, this is one of those days:

I actually didn't wrote a script... I thought I did. Instead of writing a script, I just put an alias in my .bash_profile.

I remembered when doing the `type scriptname` as jw013 suggested.

Thanks guys.

Comment: So that means that the observation that it gets run at boot was wrong? It runs on login?